# Creating an asp:Button programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servercontrols

I'm using my code-behind page to create a save button programmatically:

```
    Button btnSave = new Button();
    btnSave.ID = "btnSave";
    btnSave.Text = "Save";
```

However I think this must create an html button or perhaps needs something else as I cannot seem to set the OnClick attribute in the following line, I can specify OnClientClick but this isn't the one I want to set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Button btnSave = new Button();    
btnSave.ID = "btnSave";    
btnSave.Text = "Save";  
btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSave_Click);

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something when button clicked. 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Also remember that when the user clicks the button it will force a postback, which creates a *new instance* of your page class.  The old instance where you created the button is already gone.  You need to make sure that this new instance of the class also adds your button -- and it's event handler -- *prior to the load phase*, or the event handler won't run (the page's load event still will, however).

Answer (score 5):

You would be adding a handler to the OnClick using the += syntax if you want to register a handler for the OnClick event in the code behind.

```
//Add the handler to your button, passing the name of the handling method    
btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSave_Click);

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your custom code goes here
}
```

Comment: sorry?!

I know I'm being thick but that answer made no sense to me, what is a += syntax?