# How to add event to custom control that fired when click a button in it?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I want to build custom control consist of html code which shows table, and in the footer of this table I need to add three buttons.
What I did is inherit from WebControl class:

```
public class MyCustomControl : WebControl {  
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {  
    // using output.Write I write the table in html code  
    // and I write the three buttons using <input> tag in html not <asp:button> tag
    }  
}
```

What I want here is to add three events one to each button I wrote, and those events would be used in the user interface and fired when the proper button clicked:

```
<asp:MyCustomControl runat="server" id="myCtrl" onButton1Click="Button1_Click" onButton2Click="Button2_Click" />
```

How can I do this ?

Thanx

****UPDATE1:**
The render code in my custom control would be like this:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
    output.Write("<table> ......");
    output.Write("<input id='button1' type='button'>");
    output.Write("<input id='button2' type='button'>");
    output.Write("<input id='button3' type='button'>");
    output.Write(".........</table>");
    }
```

So how would I make 'button1' fire the event on server side?

****UPDATE2:**
This is what the code looks like:

```
public class MyCustomControl : WebControl
{

 public Button Button1 = new Button {Text = "Button1"};
 public Button Button2 = new Button {Text = "Button2"};

 public event EventHandler Button1_Click;
 public event EventHandler Button2_Click;

 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
 {
   Button1.Click += Button1Click;
   Button2.Click += Button2Click;
   base.OnPreRender(e);
 }

 protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
 {
  using (var plh = new PlaceHolder())
   {
   var htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
   htmlCode.Append("....html code for table...");

   var container = new HtmlGenericControl { InnerHtml = htmlCode.ToString() };

   plh.Controls.Add(container);
   plh.Controls.Add(Button1);
   plh.Controls.Add(Button2);
   plh.RenderControl(output);

   htmlCode.Append("..../html code for table...");
   }
 }

 private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (Button1_Click != null)
      Button1_Click(this, e);
 }

 private void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (Button2_Click != null)
      Button2_Click(this, e);
 }
```

And in the page.aspx:

```
<cc1:MyCustomControl ID="myCtrl" runat="server" onbutton1_click="MyCustomControl_Button1_Click" />
```

But even with this the button1's click method 'MyCustomControl_Button1_Click' not called.

Answer (score 0):

declare your new events like this:

```
public event EventHandler OnButton1Click;
public event EventHandler OnButton2Click;
public event EventHandler OnButton3Click;
```

this in the click method on each button do something like this:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnButton1Click != null)
        OnButton1Click(this, null);
}
```

Comment: But how would the html input button fire the server side click method like any regular asp.net button does?
like I said I'm writing the button html code manually, I didn't use ASP.NET button inside my custom control (because I don't know how to do it with three buttons and html table with it).

Comment: use asp:Buttons instead of "regular" buttons

Comment: How?..I'm writing the output result of the control using 'HtmlTextWriter' variable passed as parameter of the 'RenderContents' override method..so how can I add three asp.net buttons?

Comment: @Dabbas, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188007/creating-an-aspbutton-programatically

Comment: @Dabbas Why not use asp:Button? It will render as regular HTML on the client's machine, and you can assign to it server-side methods!

Answer (score 0):

Within `MyCustomControl` class, define events that take `(object sender, EventArgs e)` and return `void`.

Then add (still within MyCustomControl) the event handlers for the `click` events of the internal buttons.
Inside these methods, do `CustomClickEvent.Invoke()`.

Then, in the page containing your custom control, do `myControl.CustomClickEvent += new CustomClickEvent(name_of_method_within_page);`

Comment: Please see my first comment on 'Zdravko Danev' answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To render an asp control from your Custom Control do that from Render base method:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
```

Prepare before your controls with this method

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
```