# Creating Button and OnClick Event from c# side - asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button, onclick

im creating a button from c# side like this:

```
content += "<button class='btn btn-info' runat='server' style='margin-left:4%' id='Like" + dr[0] + "' onclick='likeClick'>";
```

And the event is really simple i just want to see if its working:

```
protected void likeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    content = sender.ToString();
}
```

But when i click the button it doesn't trigger the event, I put a break point in the event and I debugged but it didn't start the fucntion. I opened Inspect Element in the browser and clicked the button. It showed me this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to use html button or ASP button

Comment: I tried both but it didn't work. I think I prefer asp button.

Comment: Yes, you create asp button, have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397856/add-aspbutton-from-codebehind  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188007/creating-an-aspbutton-programatically

Comment: I tried to do it but how am I suppose to add it to the content variable?
because i can't to it like this `content += likeButton;` and also can i put html tags in it? like this: `likeButton.Text = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up' style = 'font-size:250%; color:white'></span><span style='color:white;'> 23 </span>";`
The content variable is in the aspx side `<%=content %>`
Ty for helping!

Comment: Maybe I should do it with html button?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to create a `Button` server control dynamically. The way, you are creating is wrong. You have to instantiate a `Button` object, declare the `Click` event and add it to your page. Also, since it is a dynamically created control, it will required to be re-created on every postback. Here is a sample code on similar scenario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phControl" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnButton = new Button();
        btnButton.Style.Add("margin-left", "4%");
        btnButton.ID = "like"+ dr[0];
        btnButton.Text = "Like";
        btnButton.Click += BtnButton_Click;
        phControl.Controls.Add(btnButton);
    }

    private void BtnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content = sender.ToString();
        Response.Write(content);
    }
```

Comment: I understand your answer but I need to create the buttons inside div, I have unknown number of divs because im making them dynamically - div for each record on database. Is it possible to it like that?

Comment: I can't do it like that?
 `content += "<asp:Button class='btn btn-info' runat='server' style='margin-left:4%' ID='Like" + dr[0].ToString() + "' OnClick='likeClick'>";`

Comment: No, you cannot create server controls like that. Even if  you are to create DIVs then also you can use the same mechanism shown above